# Limit of infinite product: (3n+1)/(3n+2)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

I am struggling to find the following limit: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot...\cdot(3n+1)}{2\cdot5\cdot8\cdot...\cdot(3n+2)}$$

So far I tried to use squeeze theorem and logarithm to proof that the limit is actually 1 but didn't manage to do this.

Comment: To prove that the limit is actually $1$?  Since each of $\frac{4}{5},\frac{7}{8},\dots,\frac{3n+1}{3n+2}$ is less than or equal to $1$ it follows that the product is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$...  There is no way that it could be $1$.  Did you mean to say zero?

Comment: The term is given by $$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{5}{3}\right)}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Although you ended up with the right value for $L$, I disagree with your reasoning. It seems you took the equation $a_n=\frac{3n+1}{3n+2}a_{n-1}$ and let $n\to\infty$ in part of it ($a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$) but not in the rest ($\frac{3n+1}{3n+2}$).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I still disagree with your reasoning. Why wouldn't it apply equally well to $\prod_n\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}$, which converges to a non-zero result? Calling the limit $L$, reasoning analogous (as far as I can see) to yours would produce $L=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}L$ and then $L=0$, which is incorrect.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see your point. I was doing a bit too much hand waving and did not really check my logic. On the other hand, your example is a bad one. Your example converges to zero since $$\dfrac{1^2-1}{1^2} = 0$$ But, I do get your point that this approach would not work in general.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes, I should have started my infinite product at $n=2$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n\to \infty}{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot\cdots\cdot\pars{3n + 1} \over 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 8 \cdot\cdots\cdot \pars{3n + 2}}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\prod_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{3i + 1} \over
\prod_{j = 0}^{n}\pars{3j + 2}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\prod_{i = 0}^{n}\pars{i + 1/3} \over
\prod_{j = 0}^{n}\pars{j + 2/3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\pars{1/3}^{\overline{n + 1}} \over
\pars{2/3}^{\overline{n + 1}}} =
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\Gamma\pars{1/3 + n + 1}/\Gamma\pars{1/3} \over
\Gamma\pars{2/3 + n + 1}/\Gamma\pars{2/3}} =
{\Gamma\pars{2/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\Gamma\pars{n + 4/3} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 5/3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma\pars{2/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\pars{n + 1/3}! \over \pars{n + 2/3}!} =
{\Gamma\pars{2/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}
\lim_{n\to \infty}{\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1/3}^{n + 5/6}\expo{-n - 1/3} \over \root{2\pi}\pars{n + 2/3}^{n + 7/6}\expo{-n - 2/3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma\pars{2/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\,
\lim_{n\to \infty}{n^{n + 5/6}\,
\bracks{1 + \pars{1/3}/n}^{n}\expo{-1/3} \over
n^{n + 7/6}\,\bracks{1 + \pars{2/3}/n}^{n}\expo{-2/3}} =
{\Gamma\pars{2/3} \over \Gamma\pars{1/3}}\,
\lim_{n\to \infty}{1 \over n^{1/3}} = \bbx{0}
\end{align}